# InDesign: how to expand all collapsed links

Tags: adobe-indesign, workflow, shortcuts

Is there a way to expand up all the links listed in the 'Links' panel at once?

I want to get a quick overview of all the extra info I toggle to display in links (resolution, color mode, etc.). Is there a shortcut for this?

Scripts are of limited use in my case as I use many different workstations and I cannot install new files on most of them.

[image: Links panel]

Comment: *[Awards you with the **Overthinking** badge]*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+*Click* one of the expanding arrows and they will all expand.